# How to add a message in cart for woocommerce based on item quantity

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a unique business model where our pricing increases every 3 items meaning

1-3 items in cart = X cost

4-6 items = 2X cost

7-9 items = 3x cost

If a person has 1 or 2 items in the cart, I want them to know they can still add the difference from 3 to cart and pay the same price (get the most for their money). How do I do a check for total item quantity in cart and then display msg based on the quotient if not = 0?

If you need additional information, I will gladly provide as much as I can.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Attach a function upon page load or item selection which does just what you mentioned. I may have overcomplicated this, but tried to keep it as simple as possible. Use your existing 'add item' and onload functions:

```js
var quantity = 0;

$(document).load(init());

function init() 
{
  quantity % 3 > 0 ? $('#quant').show() : $('#quant').hide();
  $('#num').html(3 - (quantity % 3));
}

function addOne() // your buy function
{
  quantity++;
  init();
  $('#total').html(quantity);
}
```

```css
div#quant 
{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quant">Buy 
  <span id="num"></span>
  more for free!
</div>
<br>
<button onclick="addOne()">Buy Item</button>
<h3>Total: <span id="total"></span></h3>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for coding this up. The issue is I'm working with woocommerce so simple things like var quantity and the button onclick are a bit more complicated and interconnected than had I built the backend myself. I can add the onclick function to simple.php. I'll load the js/jquery into a global footer. Is there anything I'm missing?